# default map reduce jobs ? how many mappers and reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

my question is how many default mappers and reducers jobs, one employer asking to me i said default mapper 4, and reducer 1, and what is Sqoop default mappers

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop runs 4 mappers by default and can be overridden with `-m` or `--num-mappers` flag.

If the table to be imported does not contain a primary key or not have `--split-by` option set in `sqoop` command, then it has to be a single map task.  Explicitly set `-m 1` or `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` to run only one map task.

**Note:** Sqoop runs Map only job (no reducers).

In a typical MapReduce Job, the number of mappers will depend on the Input (with their FileFormat) and the number of reducers defaults to 1.

For `Distcp` jobs, the number of map tasks will be equal to the number of files.

Comment: thanks franklinsijo, but mapreduce.job.maps is 2 and mapreduce.job.reduces 1 in below link i saw that  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

Comment: The reduces property will be used (that is how the number of reducers defaults to 1) whereas the maps property will be overridden by the number of inputsplits.